# How to implement dataset security permissions to separate usergroups within Power BI?

Tags: azure, powerbi, permissions

I'm working on configuring Power BI on Azure to allow a list of users access to various datasets hosted through ADF. What I'm trying to do is create a way to delineate access to the base datasets based upon security groups that users can be assigned to, granting access to specific tables only if specified. Additionally, for some of the tables access to specific columns and rows will also need to be assigned per security group.

Is there a reasonable way to enable this type of access within Power BI or are there other design or configuration elements that must be considered to achieve this gracefully?

Comment: how are you exactly refering to ADF datasteps from Power BI?
Data sets exist in ADF but they need perssistance somewhere, like Data Lake, Storage account or database.

Can you clarify that so I can try to help you with?

I know that's possible to restrict access at row level, and even column to data in sqlserver. will be glad to Post an answer based on your reply to my comment

Comment: We are using an Azure SQL database that we will connect to our sources via SSIS and other integrations. I'm not sure exactly what level of detail you're looking for beyond that item. Part of our shift here is in moving from on prem to cloud so we're figuring out several pieces in that process.

Comment: To refine the question further @PauloCorreia, I believe I'm trying to implement a way to administer both row level and object level security elements to control who can or cannot see data within my tables. I know Power BI can manage this via roles, but I'm uncertain of how to best implement that system within my data structures in a graceful way.